# SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s). sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table that named as 'data' and 'regions'. I want to get regions with data related records as item of regions records.

regions

```
RegionId -- Name -- ParentId
```

data

```
DataId -- RegiondId -- Url
```

Sample result:

```
[
{Name:"a", items:[{...},{...},{...}, ...]},
{Name:"b", items:[{...},{...},{...}, ...]},
]
```

I used this query

```
SELECT *,(
    SELECT * 
    FROM data 
    WHERE data.RegionId=regions.RegionId
) AS items 
FROM regions 
WHERE regions.ParentId=1
```

But I got `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.

Important: Region has parent relation between its records. So I when write this condition `data.RegionId=regions.Id` it must return that items has matches `RegionIds` of it's childs.

Comment: You are trying to select multiple rows in place of a single column.

Comment: Can you guide to better solution?

Answer (score 5):

A subquery in the select list must return one column and 1 row (single value), but you have a `select *` there, hence the error message.

Your query should be written as a simple inner join instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM regions 
INNER JOIN data ON data.RegionId=regions.RegionId
WHERE regions.ParentId=1
```

Comment: I think that it doesn't return result like mentioned sample, Are you sure?

Comment: The expected results is in a json format, which is just a different representation of the resultset my query produces. You can transaform the resultset in your application logic or check out MySQL's limited json support functions to transform the resultset into the format you require.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error when trying to insert several rows at once. I collected the query parameters into an array and concatenated the place holder question marks. The error was given when I had something like

```
INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES ((...),(...),(...))
```

when what I should have had was

```
INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...),(...),(...)
```

Notice the extra parenthesis that caused the error.