# mysql query two row from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this Query to call information form two table.

```
DB::get("SELECT friends. * , (SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = friends.`user_id`) AS `login` FROM `friends` WHERE `id_user`='" . $this->user['id'] . "' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ")
```

So if user is on friends list show username , i would like to get username and avatar. Avatar row is `avatar` . 
I try with this.

```
DB::get("SELECT friends. * , (SELECT `login`, `*avatar*` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = friends.`user_id`) AS `login` FROM `friends` WHERE `id_user`='" . $this->user['id'] . "' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ")
```

And give me the error

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: See answer in this possible duplicate of [**SQLSTATE\[21000\]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s). sql query**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326246/sqlstate21000-cardinality-violation-1241-operand-should-contain-1-columns) explaining that you cannot have more than 1 column returned and to use a `join` instead.

Comment: When you select multiple columns and try to assign on a single column name it never works and should be that way, as it does not make sense, think it... And mysql engine thought about it and had added an exception for this and it throws that error. Now how do we overcome as you can see some answers suggested usage of JOIN, so try using JOIN by yourself and let us know if there is some issue.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Help me with my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should use [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and Second, you can't write inline view, which has two columns

```
SELECT friends. * , (SELECT `login`, `*avatar*` FROM ..
```

instead you should use `JOIN`, which might be efficient than current approach and more readable.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` ? ?

Comment: @Martinovska That depends. `Left Join` will return common and data from the left table. I think, in your case, you should use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Where is the problem in my code? About  Prepared Statement?

Comment: @Martinovska I have posted a link, please refer that, to understand, what does prepared statement means

Comment: Thank you @Ravi , but I did not understand you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT f.*, u.*
FROM friends f JOIN users u ON f.user_id = u.id
WHERE f.id_user = <your_id>
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT <your_limit>;
```